# Angular Component, TypeScript, Two way bindings

Tags: angularjs

I've started learning and searched many web-sites for angular but looking for visual representations of angular features, flow, everything in diagram to understand it better.

```
example
    ts file
    css file
    html file
    javascript file
    end to end flow
    how does it works
```

Does anyone knows where i can conceptually get stronger in angular via diagrams rather than directly jumping into code.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking about AngularJS or Angular? AngularJS is the original version of the framework and Angular 2 and above is a complete rewrite of the original framework.

Comment: Angular JS and not just Angular

Comment: If you're a new learner, it's not a good idea to start with AngularJS, as it goes EOL at the end of the year. You'll want to stick with the latest versions of Angular, like 10.

Comment: What technologies i should learn before going to Angular js?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.